# How to remove margins around ButtonBar without removing them from the rest of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

Suppose I have a layout that looks something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greeting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, world!" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actions"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button2" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Rendered in Eclipse, I get the following:

[image]

Notice that there is a margin around the ButtonBar. Is there any way to remove this without affecting the rest of the Activity? If I modify the `android:padding*` attributes, then the "Hello, world!" will run up against the left side of the Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `android:padding*` to the `greeting` element, removing it from the parent layout. Then that item alone with have padding while the button bar will not.

If you need to add additional items later on (rather than just the single `TextView`), you would want to wrap them in a new layout and put the padding on that layout.

Comment: `greeting` is a `TextView`.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - TextViews can have padding just like any other element.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now. But what happens if I want to add some other Views to the Activity? Must I specify padding for each of them? Is there any way to have everything in the Activity have the same padding?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - I edited my answer - the easiest way would be to wrap all those Views in a new layout (say, a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout) and use that layout solely for padding purposes.

Comment: I just finished doing that after reading your edit. Everything is working fine now - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set the android:padding for each of the layout you created...
the child placed within parent layout will have the padding set for them...you can use layout_margin instead...